# Javascript promises - handle possible race condition

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I've recently encountered this question online and it's solution. Yet I do not fully understand the solution.

The question:

```
this.resources = {};

async function getResource (name) {

    if (this.resources[name]) {
        return this.resources[name]
    }

    const resource = new Resource(name)
    
    await resource.load()

    this.resources[name] = resource

    return resource
}
```

Here, in case we have a call to `getResource` with name X and during the time `load` is executed, we get another call to the function with the same name X it might create another resource with name X.

The solution to this is:

```
this.resources = {};

async function getResource (name) {

    if (this.resources[name]) {
        return this.resources[name]
    }

    const resource = new Resource(name)

    this.resources[name] = resource.load().then(()=>resource)

    return this.resource[name]
}
```

Now this solution means that first, `this.resources[name]` will hold a Promise object and then once the promise is resolved, it will hold the loaded resource.

My question is, in case we are waiting for the promise to resolve, and another call to `getResource` with name X arrives, it will pass the `if` statement, and once again call `new Resource(name)` and wait for `load` to end.

But won't that cause potentially, to have the first X resource in `this.resources[name]` to be over-riden once the second `load` completes?

Comment: you are mistaken, `this.resources[name]` will ALWAYS hold a Promise, the Promise that is returned by the `.then`, i.e. a promise that resolves to `resource`  - also, you don't need that function to be `async` anymore

Comment: But how does this promise, handle the potential race condition?

Comment: Second call will wait till the first completes. Two javascript user functions are never executed in parallel.

Comment: there is no potential race condition since `this.resources[name]` is only ever the Promise returned by `resource.load().then` and never the promise returned by `resource.load()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> another call to getResource with name X arrives, it will pass the if statement

Second call will wait till the first completes. Two javascript user functions are never executed in parallel.

That's why the first version doesn't work - the function execution ends on the await and before it continues, another call can occur.